# Android notification not showing on Oreo

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have a simple notification which works for me on older androids. But this same notification doesnt pop up on my phone with android oreo. I read that i need to assign channel with notification, which i did. But still, it doesnt pop up.

Thanks

My code -

> 

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        String name = "notification";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("New Message")
                .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .build();
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with that `Notification` object or just creating it and holding a reference in your code? Maybe something like `mManager.notify`? (Also, any reason you're not using `getSystemService(NotificationManager.class)`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing `mManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);`

Comment: yes this was the problem, silly me. Thank you very much